# WPF Document Viewer Styling

Tags: wpf, controls, controltemplate, documentviewer

I am trying to restyle the document viewer in WPF and I have restyled everything but the tool bar at the bottom.  The problem I having is figuring out how to style the toolbar at the bottom and its child controls. Does anyone know how to restyle this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The usual way would be to supply a custom `ControlTemplate`. Here is the default definition, for your reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970452.aspx.

Comment: Sorry I should have been more specific that is what I am talking about.  I have re-templated the document viewer but I am unsure of how to re-template the PART_FindToolBarHost portion of it since it is a PART.  Does this clarify my question?

Comment: You have to define a `ContentControl` with x:Name="PART_FindToolBarHost", this is expected by the `DocumentViewer` class. Beside that you can put any styling, any element structure, any nesting you would like to.

Comment: Could you please provide me with an example of styling that specific tool bar?