# Disable "Print" button in "DocumentViewer"

Tags: c#, wpf, button, data-binding

I would like to disable the button in question.

My code is:

```xml
<DocumentViewer x:Name="viewerDocument" 
                Document="{Binding GeneratedDocument}" />
```

and the preview is as follows

[image: document viewer]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367049/wpf-document-viewer-styling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to override the default template ([DocumentViewer ControlTemplate Example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/documentviewer-styles-and-templates?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#documentviewer-controltemplate-example)) or subclass `DocumentViewer` to override the `DocumentViewerBase.OnPrintCommand` method and call the `DocumentViewerBase.CancelPrint` method from the override.
You can also find the print button in the visual tree and set `UIElement.IsEnabled` to `false`.

The following example shows how to get the print button to disable it:

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<DocumentViewer Loaded="OnDocumentViewerLoaded" />
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
private void OnDocumentViewerLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  var documentViewer = (DocumentViewer)sender;
  Button printButton = EnumerateVisualChildElements<Button>(documentViewer)
    .First(button => button.Command == ApplicationCommands.Print);

  // Disable the print button
  printButton.IsEnabled = false;
}

private static IEnumerable<TChildren> EnumerateVisualChildElements<TChildren>(DependencyObject parent) where TChildren : DependencyObject
{
  for (int childIndex = 0; childIndex < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent); childIndex++)
  {
    DependencyObject childElement = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, childIndex);
    if (childElement is Popup popup)
    {
      childElement = popup.Child;
    }

    if (childElement is TChildren child)
    {
      yield return child;
    }

    foreach (TChildren item in EnumerateVisualChildElements<TChildren>(childElement))
    {
      yield return item;
    }
  }
}
```